# Ubuntu sidebar/launcher edit/remove?

Tags: unity, launcher, macosx

I would like to make my ubuntu 13.04 look like mac osx. The problem is this launcher's unity sidebar, I am not able to move it what so ever. I've done my homework and I know that it is impossible in 13.04 to move it to the bottom what so ever. So, I want to get rid of it. I know one way is to disable it by using gnome shell, but I like unity shell besides the sidebar. The question that I am trying to ask is, is there any, like ANY way to get rid of ubuntus sidebar, and use your own dock? Maybe there is some sort of shell or something. I know for the older versions, there was unity_rotated shell, but what about 13.04?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Cairo Dock](http://glx-dock.org/)?

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

To download and install click the image below.

[image: Install via the software center]

Once you install it, logout or restart the system, and when it boots back up, choose Cairo dock as shown in the images below.

[image]
[image]

When the desktop comes up, you will notice the the side launcher is not there anymore.

[image]

Comment: I have installed it, I would love to use it, but I can't get rid of ubuntu's launcher, that sidebar thing on the left of the screen. It is stupid to have two docks.

Comment: Look at the additions in my answer regarding the side launcher.

Comment: As I mentioned, I really don't want to loose that unitys sidebar at the top. If you use cairo-docks shell, you loose that bar.

Comment: You don't loose the top bar, it just look different.  look at both corners.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that, but I want to have the same bar, just like in unity. It is very important to me since it is very comfortable.